# UIGestureRecognizer causing "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

Using the GestureRecognizer attached to a view triggers my app to crash with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error. Here's the classes involved

• **BoardViewController** - Displaying a board (as background) set as rootViewController in the AppDelegate. It instantiates multiple objects of the "TaskViewcontroller".

```
//BoardViewController.h
@interface BoardViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray* allTaskViews; //for storing taskViews to avoid having them autoreleased
}
```

```
//BoardViewController.m - Rootviewcontroller, instantiating TaskViews    
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TaskViewController* taskA = [[TaskViewController alloc]init];
    [allTaskViews addObject:taskA];
    [[self view]addSubview:[taskA view]];
}
```

• **TaskViewController** - An indivual box displayed on the board. It should be draggable. Therefore I attached UIPanGestureRecoginzer to its view

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"PAN!");
}
```

The .xib file is a simple view.

[image]

All programming with the gesture recognizer I'd prefer to do in code. Any idea how to fix the error causing the app crash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `handlePan` is on your view controller, not on your view. You should set the target to `self`:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
```

**EDIT** (in response to the edit of the question) As [omz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573626/omz) has correctly noted, your `TaskViewController` gets released upon `BoardViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:` exit. There are two ways of dealing with it:

- Fold the `handlePan` method into the parent view controller, along with the code of `viewDidLoad:`, or
- Make an instance variable for `TaskViewController *taskA`, rather than making it a local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I corrected this. However now I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Any idea on this?

Comment: ARC releases your `taskA` view controller at the end of the `viewDidLoad` method (because you don't have any other reference to it), so the target becomes invalid.

Comment: Oh, yes, right. What's the best way to approach this? Creating an NSMutableArray that stores references to all task objects being instantiated?

Comment: I added an array to keep a reference to the taskViews (taskA in this case). I updated the code accordingly. I still get the “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” error.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to use Gesture Recognizer. I think this way is easy and with low risk.

At first, you drag and drop Gesture Recognizer into the view.

[image: ss]

Then, you wire the Gesture Recognizer icon to code.

[image: ss]

Finally, you write code for this IBAction like below:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"PAN!");
}
```

You can download this project from GitHub and just run it.

https://github.com/weed/p120812_PanGesture

Comment: Thanks for this. However as mentioned I really would prefer doing it in code. Furthermore I do not use Storyboards. :)